# JIRA anonymous REST API calls

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

Maybe someone know how I can make anonymous calls to my Rest endpoints.

Now when I not logged in, I receive response with 401 status and Unauthorized msg.
All my rest endpoints works after Jira logging in.

```
 <rest key="rest" path="/config-admin" version="1.0">
        <description>Provides REST resources</description>
    </rest>


@Path("/customer")
public class QBConnector {
    @POST
    public String connect(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
    .....
    return "test";
    }
}
```

I try to use *@AnonymousAllowed* annotation, but when I just add *com.atlassian.plugins.rest* dependecy to maven's pom.xml, and after pulgin deployment when I try to call my endpoint I just received 'Oops, you've found a dead link.'

Comment: which url are you calling for test?

Comment: Localhost:8081/rest/config-admin/1.0/customer